# Henry Hatsworth, how to climb down and get out of Mysteria Stage 1-5

Tags: henry-hatsworth

I'm playing *Henry Hatsworth and the Puzzling Adventure* for the Nintendo DS.
I seem to have trapped poor Henry partway through Stage 1-5 in Mysteria (the first cemetery level).  He can't jump up, and I've tried blasting through the floor with his sword, but that doesn't work either.

Because it's the DS, I don't know how to get a screen shot.

My hypotheses:

- I am totally incompetent at jumping and will need to start over
- I need some godawful key combo to jump higher
- If I can manage to enable the robot suit, it will be able to jump higher than regular Henry can jump

**How can I get Henry out of the trap?** Feedback and ideas welcomed.

Comment: Are you talking about the gauntlet style areas with the purple one eyed enemies that shoot at you?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete video walkthrough for that level:

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to go *down* at around 4:49 in the walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a walkthrough.  It turns out that if Henry is on a thin floor,

> Henry can climb *down* by holding the down direction on the + controller and then pressing the B button.

Why this move isn't in the manual I surely don't know.  But climbing down gets Henry out of the trap.